# How add include and library paths in Eclipse when using Docker containers

Tags: eclipse, docker, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, docker-container

I installed Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers 2019-09 R (4.13.0) and I want to build my C++ project inside a Docker container.

To do so, I checked the checkbox "Build inside a docker container" in Project Properties:

[Eclipse build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPSiL.png)

Once I did it, Eclipse creates include index and shows me what include paths are loaded from the docker container based on my docker image:

[Include index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR8WN.png)

It seems that Eclipse only loads the include system paths installed in the docker images. **What I want is to use an include path out of the default system include path**. I tried to look for some kind of include configuration or documentation about that but I did not find anything.

I tried to create a soft link in /usr/include pointing to the external (non-default) include path when the docker image is being created but Eclipse did not find them either.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Emilio Garcia

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to include the path inside the container in the settings for the preprocessor include path provider. Before checking "Build inside docker container" (or before clicking Apply to that change), go to "C/C++ General|Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc." in the project settings and select the "Providers" tab. Then, click "CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Settings" (or the equivalent for the tool chain you selected). Below that, in the box with "Command to get compiler specs" add the include path option before the final "{$INPUTS}" argument. For example, for include files for ROS Melodic in a container, I used:
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD -I/opt/ros/melodic/include/ "${INPUTS}"

The include files in that path will be copied when CDT copies all include files from the container.

I have tested this in a Makefile project with CDT 2021-03 (version 10.2.0)

Answer (score -1):

The include paths are set in a Managed project using the Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings dialog.  Go to the compiler Includes tree item and click.  From the right hand side, you can add include paths to specify on the build (e.g. /usr/include/gtk-2.0)  Creating a soft link won't do anything because headers are used from the image (not your local system) plus any mounted directories.

Note that if your include path is one belonging to a package (e.g. gtk2-devel), then you need to install that package on your image.  There a few ways to do this, but I like starting a shell (either docker run -it /bin/sh or use the Docker Views menu Run icon) in the base image and then in the shell install the package using the appropriate mechanism (dnf, yum, apt).  After installing, leave the container running and commit the image (either use docker commit yourrepo:yourtag or do it from the right-click menu of the running container from the Docker Containers View).  Then,  specify your new image to use in the Container Settings page from now on.

If the headers are local files written by you and not in the project, then add the directory in the Container Settings -> Data Volumes list (where you clicked to enable container builds for your managed project).  This will mount the directory in the container so your build can access it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your reply!

I meant that, I installed some dependencies like boost 1.58 compiling from source and I put them in another location different from system defaults when the docker image is being created.

So, my docker image has the boost 1.58 installed in /usr/local/ieec/labs/dep/boost-1.58. So my intent was to create to soft link in /usr/include/ to point to that location.

I will try to add the includes using Build -> Settings -> Tool Setings. I thought this option was aimed to include local includes not includes which are inside the docker images :D

Thanks again!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this approach? Eclipse does not seem to copy non-standard directories from the container. So even if you specify your the include directory in Tool Settings, the headers will not be available.

Comment: No, the only solution that I think is installing the dependencies of my software in system default paths :(